# Starting async/await from any arbitrary (synchronous) method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, hangfire

If I have a regular method call and I need to 'start' using async/await, what is best way to initiate that?  Without going into too much detail, I'm using Hangfire to process jobs and due to some scenarios that I *think* are outside scope of the question, the Hangfire job is run synchronously, but then I want to later on initiate async and await so that the actual 'job code' can use async/await as needed/desired.  Is below the best way to enable async and await?

```
public void SynchMethod()
{
    var inputPackage = XElement.Parse( "NormallyPassedIn" );
    var hangfireJob = CreateJob( inputPackage );

    Task.Run( async () =>
    {
        // This Execute method implementation wants to use await on several
        // helper methods it calls, so this is how I thought to allow for that
        await hangfireJob.Execute( inputPackage );
    } ).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

**Update 2: Block as high up as I can...**

So trying to take Stephen's advice of blocking as high up as possible (basically on first/only cross domain call), I tried to change my code to the following:

```
var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain( info.ApplicationName, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, info );
...
instance = appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap( jobInvokerType.Assembly.FullName, jobInvokerType.FullName ) as JobInvoker;
...
instance.Process( this, inputPackage.ToString() ).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

With Process function as:

```
public async Task Process( IHangfireJobContext jobContext, string inputPackageXml )
{
...
    var hangfireJob = CreateJob( assembly, jobTypeName );

    await hangfireJob.Execute( inputPackage, jobContext );
}
```

Remember that `hangfireJob.Execute` is the 'real' method where I want to be able to use async/await.  As soon as `hangfireJob.Execute` used `await`, the following exception was thrown:

> Type
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' in Assembly 'mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is
>   not marked as serializable.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType
>   type)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type
>   type, StreamingContext context)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object
>   obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context,
>   SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter,
>   ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object
>   obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context,
>   SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter,
>   ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object
>   graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.SerializeMessageParts(ArrayList
>   argsToSerialize)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodReturnMessage..ctor(IMethodReturnMessage
>   mrm)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodReturnMessage.SmuggleIfPossible(IMessage
>   msg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoDispatch(Byte[]
>   reqStmBuff, SmuggledMethodCallMessage smuggledMcm,
>   SmuggledMethodReturnMessage& smuggledMrm)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoTransitionDispatchCallback(Object[]
>   args)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   BTR.Evolution.Hangfire.JobInvoker.Process(IHangfireJobContext
>   jobContext, String inputPackageXml)    at
>   BTR.Evolution.Hangfire.JobInvoker.Invoke(XElement inputPackage,
>   PerformContext performContext, IJobCancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) in
>   C:\BTR\Source\Evolution\BTR.Evolution.Hangfire\JobInvoker.cs:line 86

So I changed back to:

`public void Process( IHangfireJobContext jobContext, string inputPackageXml )`

And moved the `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` to the end of hangfireJob.Execute() instead:

`hangfireJob.Execute( inputPackage, jobContext ).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

And then everything worked.  Marking Stephen's answer as correct.  Not sure why I couldn't block on the first/only call going cross domain but maybe that is expected.

**Update 1: AppDomain creation/reasoning**

So I thought I would update the question based on the comments below.  My work flow that really runs is below and the main issue I have is the fact that I'm creating an AppDomain and calling across domains.

1. Hangfire kicks off my job (`JobInvoker.Invoke`) to run (you can have your job be a synchronous or an asynchronous job).  So originally, I tried to run as asynchronously as `public async Task Invoke( XElement inputPackage, PerformContext performContext, IJobCancellationToken cancellationToken )`.
2. `JobInvoker.Invoke` creates an AppDomain via `var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain( info.ApplicationName, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, info );`
3. `JobInvoker.Invoke` creates an object via `instance = appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap( jobInvokerType.Assembly.FullName, jobInvokerType.FullName )`.
4. I tried calling the `instance.Process` method that had a signature `public async Task Process( IHangfireJobContext jobContext, string inputPackageXml )`.
5. `instance.Process` created an object via reflection with code from above `var hangfireJob = CreateJob()`.  This `hangfireJob` object has the method that I need to have `async` in the signature.
6. `instance.Process` called hangfireJob via `await hangfireJob.Execute()`.
7. `hangfireJob.Execute` signature was `public async Task Execute( XElement inputPackage, IHangfireJobContext jobContext )`.

Then the code looked much nicer in the fact that I got to just put `async` on all my methods and use `await` as I please.  But as soon as `hangfireJob.Execute` tried to use `await` and I received the following exception (remember this is running in separate AppDomain, thus the exception):

> Type
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' in Assembly 'mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is
>   not marked as serializable.

So that is why I tried 'introducing' asynchronous coding from within `instance.Process` (which was essentially represented by my original `SynchMethod`), because my `hangfireJob.Execute` method is what really needs to have `async` on the signature so I can do some `await` calls.

Given this information, maybe all the comments don't exactly apply anymore?  Let me know if you think they do or if it is as simple as doing `await hangfireJob.Execute( inputPackage ).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` (and get rid of the `Task.Run` wrapper).

Comment: This code doesn't really make sense, why not just `hangfireJob.Execute(inputPackage).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`?

Comment: I suspect that you don't have a clear understanding of what await actually does.  `await` is `return`, the same way that `yield` in an iterator block is `return`. An `await` just means "if this task isn't finished, sign up the rest of this method to run later, and return now".  Await doesn't "start" anything; await *returns if a started task is not yet finished*.

Comment: I don't understand why the code is not simply `public async Task MyMethod() { await CreateJob(Parse(whatever)); }`, end of story.

Comment: @EricLippert: Maybe you see my partial misunderstanding through the updates, but your first comment was enlightening...I guess the reason I didn't do what you suggested in second comment is because then the call to MyMethod() needed await but method wasn't async...so at some point I just wanted to 'enable' the ability to use async/await.  I think the `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is the ticket (albeit a bit weird behavior described in *Update 2* probably due to my lack of AppDomain knowledge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should strongly avoid blocking on asynchronous code in the general case.

An exception to this rule is the `Main` method on Console apps.

An interesting quirk of Win32 services is that they are architecturally similar to Console apps. Specifically, they have a "main" that that should not exit until the service stops, and they have no `SynchronizationContext` provided. Thus, it is appropriate to block in your service implementation.

However, I recommend that you follow the same best practice as blocking in a Console app: only block at one point, as far up the stack as possible.

As far as the specifics go, a `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is sufficient; there's no need for `Task.Run`.

Comment: Given the question update describing AppDomain creation, could you let me know if your answer (which I referenced basically at the end of the question update) still applies?

Comment: @Terry: AFAIU, it should work fine, because there won't be any tasks crossing AppDomains.

Comment: Thanks.  Given my situation, think your comment about 'following the same best practice' can be vetoed in this situation?  Or more correctly, that this is as high up as I can go?

Comment: @Terry: Sounds like it. Technically, tasks can cross in-memory app domains, but it's a pain and not worth it IMO.

Comment: You can see my 'Update 2' on strange happening and hopefully the solution when trying to just use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult`.  Let me know if solution seems wrong.  Thanks again for all the advice.

Comment: @Terry: That looks right. Tasks are not serializable by themselves.